# Column doesnt get wrapped properly

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I am reversing the table to sideways and using the `p{Xcm}` in order to get wrapped the column within a tabular, as such:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{\textit{Overview of the biochemical tests for characterization of mastitis causing bacteria and the expected results of E. coli and S. uberis isolates}}
\label{tabelb}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|l|l|l|l|l|} \\ \hline

\textbf{\LARGE{Gram}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Group}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Name}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Colony morphology \ on blood agar}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Colony morphology on},\ CHROMager orientation} & \textbf{\LARGE{Hemolysis}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Microscopy}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Catalase test}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Coagulase test}} & \textbf{\LARGE{KOH test}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Comments}} \\ \hline
\LARGE{Negative} & \LARGE{Escherichia} & \LARGE{\textit{E. coli}} & \LARGE{Medium size (2-3 mm in diameter), grayish}& \LARGE{Pink} & \LARGE{-} & \LARGE{Rod-shape, motile} & \LARGE{+} & & \LARGE{+} & \LARGE{Hemolytic may appear} \\ \hline
\LARGE{Positive}& \LARGE{Streptococcus} & \LARGE{\textit{S. uberis}} & \LARGE{Small size (1 mm in diameter), translucent } & \LARGE{Blue} & \LARGE{-} & \LARGE{Cocci in pair or chains} & \LARGE{-} & \LARGE{-} & \LARGE{-} & \LARGE{Mucoid may appear }\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip
\scriptsize
\\
\textit{\textbf{Hemolysis (-)} = Non-hemolytic ; \textbf{Catalase test (+)} = Positive; \textbf{Catalase test (-)} = Negative; \textbf{Coagulase test (-)} = Negative; \textbf{KOH test (+)} = Positive; \textbf{KOH test (-)} = Negative.}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

However the words are getting spaces in between: 
[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: I suppose you want left aligned instead of justified text in the `p` type columns. To get thus, use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{...}`or define a custom column type for this.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also clarify: Is there a special reason for using `\Large` throughout the table? Also `\scriptsize` seems to be exceptionally small, especially in comparison with the `\Large` table contents.

Comment: Use `{\RaggedLeft}p{x cm}` in your table preamble (load `ragged2e` and `array`). However, I think you should use a `tabularx` environment.

Comment: Thank you man it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two attempts to redesign your table to make it fint into the textwidth of a landscape page:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage[textfont=it]{caption}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Overview of the biochemical tests for characterization of mastitis causing bacteria and the expected results of E. coli and S. uberis isolates}
\label{tabelb}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lllYYcYcccY@{}} 
\toprule
\thead{Gram} 
    & \thead{Group} 
        & \thead{Name} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Colony morphology on}} 
                    & \thead{Hemolysis} 
                        & \thead{Microscopy} 
                            & \thead{Catalase\\ test} 
                                & \thead{Coagulase\\ test} 
                                    & \thead{KOH\\ test} 
                                        & \thead{Comments} \\ \cmidrule{4-5}
& & & \thead{blood agar} & \thead{CHROMager\\ orientation}\\
\midrule
Negative 
    &  Escherichia 
        &  \textit{E. coli} 
            &  Medium size (2-3 mm in diameter), grayish
                &  Pink 
                    &  - 
                        &  Rod-shape, motile 
                            &  + 
                                & 
                                    &  + 
                                        &  Hemolytic may appear \\ 
Positive
    &  Streptococcus 
        &  \textit{S. uberis} 
            &  Small size (1 mm in diameter), translucent  
                &  Blue 
                    &  - 
                        &  Cocci in pair or chains 
                            &  - 
                                &  - 
                                    &  -
                                         &  Mucoid may appear \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\medskip

\footnotesize
\textit{\textbf{Hemolysis (-)} = Non-hemolytic ; \textbf{Catalase test (+)} = Positive; \textbf{Catalase test (-)} = Negative; \textbf{Coagulase test (-)} = Negative; \textbf{KOH test (+)} = Positive; \textbf{KOH test (-)} = Negative.}
\end{sidewaystable}


\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Overview of the biochemical tests for characterization of mastitis causing bacteria and the expected results of E. coli and S. uberis isolates}
\label{tabelb}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lYlcYcccY@{}} 
\toprule
\thead{Group \\ \textit{Name} (Gram)} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Colony morphology on}} 
                & \thead{Hemolysis} 
                    & \thead{Microscopy} 
                        & \thead{Catalase\\ test} 
                            & \thead{Coagulase\\ test} 
                                & \thead{KOH\\ test} 
                                    & \thead{Comments} \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
 & \thead{blood agar} & \thead{CHROMager\\ orientation}\\
\midrule
\makecell[tl]{Escherichia\\ \textit{E. coli} (Negative)} 
            &  Medium size (2-3 mm in diameter), grayish
                &  Pink 
                    &  - 
                        &  Rod-shape, motile 
                            &  + 
                                & 
                                    &  + 
                                        &  Hemolytic may appear \\ 
\makecell[tl]{Streptococcus\\ \textit{S. uberis} (Positive)} 
            &  Small size (1 mm in diameter), translucent  
                &  Blue 
                    &  - 
                        &  Cocci in pair or chains 
                            &  - 
                                &  - 
                                    &  -
                                         &  Mucoid may appear \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\medskip

\footnotesize
\textit{\textbf{Hemolysis (-)} = Non-hemolytic ; \textbf{Catalase test (+)} = Positive; \textbf{Catalase test (-)} = Negative; \textbf{Coagulase test (-)} = Negative; \textbf{KOH test (+)} = Positive; \textbf{KOH test (-)} = Negative.}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```